# Ruby undefined variable in method body

Tags: ruby

When I run this, I get an error stating that city is undefined.
What should I do?

```
 def ticket_format
   text = ""
  tickets.each do |price, artist|
    if city == "chicago"
      text += "#{artist} show will cost #{price}"
    else
      text += "You paid #{price} to see #{artist}"
     end
  end
  text
end
```

Comment: Unless `city` is global, it doesn't look like it is in the scope of the method.

Comment: You should ... define `city`, of course.

Comment: What should you do?  *Define `city`* **somewhere**.

Comment: It is defined in another file that is using this method.

Comment: Then you are not asking the right question.

Comment: If “it is defined in another file that is using this method,” then you obviously need to pass it to the method as a parameter: `ticket_format(city)`.

Answer (score 2):

the way `city` is used, means that it's whether a local variable, i.e defined in the function body, or a method defined on the same context where the `ticket_format` is defined.

unlike Procs and Lambdas (or blocks in generale), methods in ruby are not closures, i.e they do not keep the context where they were defined. So even if you define the city variable before the method

```
  city = 'a ctiy'
  def ticket_format

     city == 'a city'
     ...
  end

  # this will raise an error 'undefined local variable or method "city"'
  ticket_format
```

so whether you pass the `city` as a argument, or you define a method `city` on the same class where `ticket_format` is defined

```
 def city
   @city 
 end

 def ticket_format
    if city == 'a city'
    ...
 end
```

or

```
 def ticket_format city
    if city == 'a city'
    ...
 end
```